How Can a Mathematician with Programming Experience Transition to Hands-On Data Science and ML?
I have a strong foundation in mathematics and programming, but limited hands-on experience with the data science skills currently in demand in the industry. I am eager to start applying my knowledge practically. Could anyone recommend resources, small projects, or community collaborations to help me gain practical experience in data science and ML? I would love to contribute to any project where I can add value and learn new skills. Any guidance on entry-level roles or internships to kickstart my journey would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
